# Same Julia code, different results in different editors

Tags: visual-studio-code, scope, julia

This Julia code runs ok in JupyterLab but gives me a scope error in Vscode.  Why is there a difference? Is there a setup parameter in Vscode that I need to look at?

```
x = 0
for i in 1:5
    x += (1/i)^2
    println(i, "  ", x)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can learn more about variable scopes in Julia [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/). In particular this table:

[image]

For an explanation of how assignment works with different scopes:

When `x = <value>` occurs in a local scope, Julia applies the following rules to decide what the expression means based on where the assignment expression occurs and what `x` already refers to at that location:

1. **Existing local:** If `x` is *already a local variable*, then the existing local `x` is assigned;
2. **Hard scope:** If `x` is *not already a local variable* and assignment occurs inside of any hard scope construct (i.e. within a `let` block, function or macro body, comprehension, or generator), a new local named `x` is created in the scope of the assignment;
3. **Soft scope:** If `x` is *not already a local variable* and all of the scope constructs containing the assignment are soft scopes (loops, `try`/`catch` blocks, or `struct` blocks), the behavior depends on whether the global variable `x` is defined:

   - if global `x` is *undefined*, a new local named `x` is created in the scope of the assignment;
   - if global `x` is *defined*, the assignment is considered ambiguous:

     - in *non-interactive* contexts (files, eval), an ambiguity warning is printed and a new local is created;
     - in *interactive* contexts (REPL, notebooks), the global variable `x` is assigned.

In particular, the difference between REPL and non-REPL contexts is probably what is tripping you up.

Comment: One could also mention that this solution is a compromise, since so many users complained about the lack of 'soft-scope' behavior in the REPL, while its absense is an advantage for scripts. Hence this somewhat awkward divide.